# Sonarqube Plugin - Getting issues and characteristic

Tags: sonarqube

I've spent days trying to figure out how to get all issues by characteristic.

My scenario is that I want to know how many issuess affects the maintainability and what's the severity of that issue. Ideally I want this for all charactistic, maintainability, readability etc.

I've been looking at the sourcecode for the technical debt pyramid, just can't seem to figure out how I get it.

Thank you

Best regards Martin

Answer (score 0):

You have no direct connection between issues and characteristics:

- An issue is generated by a rule
- A rule is "attached" to a characteristic

So you have to sort issues by rule, and then sort rules by characteristic.